# Is there a more efficient way to scrape a large number of URLs (> 30k)?

Tags: javascript, ruby, elasticsearch, phantomjs, nokogiri

I operate an online store that deals in collectible goods, the market prices of which are perpetually in flux based on consumer demand.

I have recently begun to keep a record of my competitors' prices by daily running a ruby script (a rake task) which works through a list of ~30k URLs, grabs a few relevant pieces of data, and stuffs them into an Elasticsearch index. I rely on Nokogiri and PhantomJS in order to accomplish this since not all of the sites will properly render the data I need without running the JavaScript.

My program currently eats ~4GB of memory while running, and PhantomJS accounts for the vast majority of that consumption (~2.5GB). The script also takes many hours to run - I'm not exactly sure how long but I think it's more than 10 hours.

I am very open to suggestions about how to reduce my memory consumption and improve the rate at which I can scrape. I wish that my competitors would provide me with a nice JSON API, but unfortunately we don't have that kind of relationship.

Comment: On sites that can be scraped *without* JavaScript, implement an alternative path. Increase concurrency - throttle based on actual CPU load. (Also, where is the other 1.5GB going? :-/)

Comment: You are asking us to give opinions based on general best-practices which you could find by searching around the internet. If you want specific information you'll have to give us details about your system and code. See "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: Don't run a daily script, run the scraping continuously in auxiliary code, with appropriate throttling. Keep track of the last time a page was checked and don't do it again in less than n hours, keeping in mind that being a good net citizen means not beating up other people's hosts or their bandwidth; Use HTTP HEAD requests to see if their page changed since you last looked.

Comment: I can guarantee that you can get the price data without PhantomJS. I've never seen a store that I needed Javascript to scrape and I've done thousands of them.

Comment: @pguardiario - yeah, I think you're right... I've been looking at each site more carefully to see how I can remove my dependence on phantom

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious things to work on are identifying which sites need the full browser treatment and which can be ripped directly without needing any of that.

The second thing is to inspect the JavaScript application that's being run to see if there's any way to get the data you need directly from the APIs it's utilizing. It's normally the case in a client-side application (e.g. Angular, React, Ember) that there's some kind of JSON API that it communicates to the server with. If you can interface directly with that API it actually massively simplifies your data collection process: You might not even have to parse any HTML at all!

Ruby is generally pretty good when it comes to processing things, but it isn't always the most efficient. Something to consider is if using JRuby and threads might increase performance, normally it's a drop-in replacement that runs ~40% faster, though at the expense of a higher initial memory footprint.

You may also want to explore the viability of using Node.js to do a lot of the dirty work of fetching/executing JavaScript, as it's pretty light-weight compared to a lot of the JavaScript runtimes for Ruby. It may even serve as a pretty good pre-fetcher that can then hand over the content to your Ruby back-end for more processing.

Building a hybrid system like that is pretty easy with a database, Redis or RabbitMQ middle layer that acts as a queue or persistence mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I think in most cases I won't be able to tap into an API directly for the data, but I was able to discover some shortcuts that I can take by inspecting the JavaScript on the website I'm scraping.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you can do increase the rate of scraping and keeping the memory consumption low without compromising the throughput.

To reduce the memory consumption, you can persist the URLs in a flat file or a database rather than putting it in memory though a data structure.

Also empty your data structure of any data after few iterations.

I am assuming that you are making requests sequentially as the average time taken per scraping a URL is greater than 1.2 seconds (10*60*60/30000 = 1.2). You can do an asynchronous call to bunch of requests at a time as your code will be waiting for one request to be completed until it makes the next one.

You can refer to "[Building blocks of a scalable web crawler](http://blog.marc-seeger.de/assets/papers/thesis_seeger-building_blocks_of_a_scalable_webcrawler.pdf)" which covers most of the aspects for scalable scraping.

These are few of the suggestions that I can give as I don't have any information about your code.

Comment: [Typhoeus and Hydra](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) make a particularly good parallel processing combination for HTTP.

Comment: I actually just started working on using flat files instead of keeping so much information in memory. Thank you for the link to the pdf - that is a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue you should save your time and go with a SaaS offering.

- [Datafiniti](https://datafiniti.co/products/product-data/) offers access to pricing and other data on products using their existing, ongoing database of over 80 million products. If they don't already have the data you're after, they may well be interested in adding it.
- [80legs](http://80legs.com/) offers on-demand custom web crawling based on your parameters. You can crawl as often as many URLs as you like, as often as you like, then get data back via API or dashboard.
- [Import.io](https://www.import.io/) offers custom crawling and extraction with a slick UI on top of it. Like 80legs, plus fairly robust extraction built-in. Again, set it up, crawl for data as often as you like, and retrieve results via an API or dashboard.

I believe there's a time and a place to roll-your-own feature. If you wanted to build this out as your own IP for valuation reasons, for example, or if you considered this crawling a core competency of your organization (i.e. it's a competitive advantage). But, given that you need it to work well and aren't in the business of crawling, this is a great time to stand on the shoulders of someone else.

Comment: Thank you for those links, I am looking into the possibility of using one of those services for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you're running your **scraper** on single thread (because of time needed to finish). You should consider running your script on multiple threads.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm

Comment: I am going to try running on multiple threads as per your suggestion. I am not sure why this answer was downvoted as I think this will likely decrease the overall run time.